# Normal Distribution with Regards to Time and Percentages

Tags: probability, statistics, average

The length of time for students to complete a test is found to be normally distributed with mean 70 minutes
and standard deviation 12 minutes. How long should the time for the test be if we wish for 90 percent of
the students to complete the test in less time than the test length?
(Use the Normal table provided for your calculations)

Comment: Wha is the $90$-th percentile of the standard normal?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  look in the normal table to find how many standard deviations you need to be above the mean to have $90\%$ of the area to the left.

How does the $-6\sigma $ student finish in $-2$ minutes?

Comment: To find the 90% do we just look at the table when the Z-score is 0.9 to get 0.8159? Or do we find the closest number to 0.9 and get the Z-score from there for which we would get .8997 to find a Z-score of 1.28?

Comment: You should go read up on Z scores and learn what the table is telling you.  This is the correct approach.  Note that deviations from the mean can be several standard deviations, but you can't have more than $100\%$ of the population with a Z score lower than something.